# The method executeQuery() cannot take arguments on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement. Error

Tags: java, sql-server, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am having this kind of error when trying to connect and retrieve data from my database.

The method executeQuery() cannot take arguments on a PreparedStatement or CallableStatement.

My code goes like this.

```
String search = request.getParameter("searchstudent");
out.println(search);

String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Chingdb;   integratedSecurity=true;";
 Connection connection = null;
 PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
 ResultSet rs = null;
int updateQuery = 0;


if(request.getParameter("editstudent")!= null){ 
    try {           
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");
     String queryString = "SELECT P_ID, lname, fname, mname FROM stu_info Where lname = ?";
     pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
     pstatement.setString(1, search);
     rs = pstatement.executeQuery(queryString);
        updateQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();
        %>
        <TABLE cellpadding="15" border="1" style="background-color: #ffffcc;">
        <%
        while (rs.next()) {
        %>
        <TR>
        <TD><%=rs.getInt(1)%></TD>
        <TD><%=rs.getString(2)%></TD>
        <TD><%=rs.getString(3)%></TD>
        <TD><%=rs.getString(4)%></TD>
        </TR></TABLE>
        <% 

        rs.close();
        pstatement.close();
        connection.close();

        }
        }

    catch(Exception e){
    out.println(e);
    }

   }
```

Comment: Remove the `executeUpdate()` call. It will generate an error, as the `PreparedStatement` does not contain an SQL update statement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you don't need the queryString the second time, because you "told" the preparedStatement the String with this:

```
pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
```

this would be the right way:

```
 pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
 pstatement.setString(1, search);
 rs = pstatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried this advise, unfortunately it didn't showed any data from my database in my web. I think there's something wrong in the try clause. -_-

Comment: @Ching29 Far more likely that there's something wrong with the query or the database or your expectations.

Comment: I already got the answer. I just deleted the

int updateQuery = 0;

statement. Btw, thanks for the help. ^_^

Answer (score 3):

try

```
 rs = pstatement.executeQuery();
```

you have already specified query while creating preparedstatement in

```
 pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried your advise, unfortunately it didn't showed any data from my database in my web. -_-

Answer (score 2):

Just add `{ }` for your querystring.i.e

```
String queryString = "{SELECT P_ID, lname, fname, mname FROM stu_info Where lname = ?}";
```

`execute()` and `executeUpdate()` will both work. `executeQuery()` only works when your procedure returns a result set.